# Stuck at initial setup screen: PS button not responding

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

Hoping to get some help with a problem I have with my PS4, which I just can't figure out. Any help would be really appreciated.

A couple of weeks ago, I was prompted to install an update, which I did using a flash drive. When the PS4 restarted, I was presented with the screen below "Connect the DUALSHOCK 4 wireless controller using the USB cable and then press the PS button"(Initial setup screen).

[image: PS4Connect the DUALSHOCK 4 wireless controller using the USB cable and then press the PS button Initial setup screen.]

I connected my brand-new, official DS via a USB and pressed the PS button, but it didn't respond. It might be relevant to note that this was a brand new controller and has never been synced with this PS4, but who knows. I tried 12 different USB cables, three of which are undoubtedly data-transfer capable cables and the best I got from the DS was the orange light charge and blinking white, when attempting to pair. I've also reset the control a number of times.

I've powered down the PS4 itself, completely a number of times and gone back through all of the safe mode options again.

I started in safe mode and have proceeded to action each and every one of the options in safe mode. I have only been able to do that, using my unofficial, wired controller, that at recognised in safe mode at least, but again, none of the options have worked. I'm stumped. Anyone every had this and fixed it? Thanks all.

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: Try to download the update again or just rollback to the previous version. Try to use a different controller. And maybe some other stuff I forgot... maybe just contact their customer support.